# How do I set IE to not store anything in the cache during development/testing?

Tags: .net, asp.net, internet-explorer, caching, browser-cache

I'm creating an Asp.NET site and I'm testing it in IE. Sometimes when I change the code and refresh the page, the changes don't get "seen," and I have to clear the cache and private data in IE. Is there a way to turn off this caching browser-side just for development? I want the functionality there in production, but it's annoying while working on the site.

Comment: What you need is the porn mode ("Private browsing" in Firefox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press `Ctrl + F5` to refresh the page.  That does a hard refresh and forces all of the resources to be downloaded again.  The IE developer toolbar also has an option that lets you clear the cache.

Comment: For future readers: In my IE 11 it was holding onto a couple css resources  for refreshes I think because I had the developer window open (F12). After closing it and pressing `ctrl + f5` it picked up the changed css files. I found this out after spamming `ctrl + f5` about 20 times and not seeing any changes.

Answer (score 2):

Also helps to change the browsing history setting in IE, Tools -> options -> General ->Browsing history settings -> change check for newer version of pages to everytime I visit the page

This will ensure that IE isn't caching anything and always asking for the latest from the server.

Answer (score 1):

You could have your base page (or an individual page) that does the following:

```
 // Checks for debug mode
 if (HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)
 {
     Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache);
     Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
 }
```

Check for debug mode which you probably would have your app in for development and then disable caching at the response level.  It's not a 100% solution but it should be enough for what you need.